# Can develop with Django using an android Phone?

Tags: android, python, django

I'm developing a web app, but sometimes I am not in my office, so I want to know if there is a way to develop from my phone using Django framework.

I tried with QPython app but cannot install Django on device. I appreciate that someone can help me with a guide for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options for this :

- Use [Django with QPython](http://pypi.qpython.org/index.php/qpython-django/)
- Use [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) which allows you to Host, run, and code Python in the cloud .
- Install a Linux on your phone ( There are [couple](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dyndns.sven_ola.debian_kit&hl=en) [of](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid&hl=en) [ways](http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) to do it )
- Use [SL4A](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) which brings scripting languages to Android . ( not sure if django is supported though )
- Connect to your Development box with some android SSH Client .